# Post digit to call status change in twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there a way I can get the chosen input digit to be sent to the callback status handler.

I'm setting up google analytics tracking as in this example https://www.twilio.com/blog/capture-call-tracking-metrics-google-analytics-twilio-programmable-voice

I'd like to be able to record in analytics which numeric option was chosen

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you request input from someone over the phone, you use the [`<Gather>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). When the user presses a button Twilio will make a request to the URL you set as the [`action` attribute for the `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action). This doesn't cause any status callback events, however it is still sending the `Digits` parameter to your application.

If you want to record the `Digits` through Google Analytics, then I would write the function to do so in the code that is called in your `action` URL webhook.